# Finding the distribution with greatest Hellinger distance

Tags: discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

Given a discrete probability distribution, how do I find the distribution that has greatest Hellinger distance from it?

Hellinger distance is given by $H(P,Q) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{\sum{}_i^k(\sqrt{p}_i - \sqrt{q}_i)^2}$, where P and Q are the two probability measures on the same set of outcomes, and $p_i$, $q_i$ are individual corresponding probability values for discrete outcomes from P and Q respectively.

Example: I have a random variable $X$ which can take values $x_1, x_2$. If my current distribution is $P(x_1)=1, P(x_2)=0$, then to maximize Hellinger distance, I would have to set $P(x_1)=0, P(x_2)=1$.

If $P(x_1)=0.5, P(x_2)=0.5$, I would need to set either $P(x_1)=1, P(x_2)=0$, or $P(x_1)=0, P(x_2)=1$.

How can I generalise this for values $x_1,x_2,...x_n$?

In the case where I have just two possible outcomes, let's say outcome $x_0$ has the higher probability. I would:

1. Set $P(x_0)$ to $0$
2. Add the old value of $P(x_0)$ to $P(x_1)$

Done.

But when I have three or more outcomes, I lose that intuition...

Update: Here's a partial intuitive answer:
I gain most by "toppling" the largest pile and moving it, so I would start by picking the outcome with the largest probability measure, set it to $0$, and add it's value to the one with the smallest. The outcome that has been moved "from" will not have any further changes to it's probability value. The one picked as a "destination" will never be decreased, only added to.

Then I recursively repeat the process until I run out of outcomes to process.

This... would result in the the least likely outcome ending up with all of the probability mass.

Is there a closed form way of saying this?

Comment: What's the Hellinger distance?

Comment: I edited my question to include a description!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note $$H^2(p,q) = 1 - \sum_i \sqrt{p_i q_i}.$$
So we want to choose $q$ to minimize $\sum_i \sqrt{p_i q_i}$, with the constraint $\sum_i q_i=1$

If we rewrite this as $x_i=\sqrt{p_i}$ and $y_i=\sqrt{q_i}$, note that we are simply finding $y$ to minimize $x^\top y$ subject to $\|y\|_2^2=1$ and $y_i \ge 0$. Geometrically, we are finding the unit vector $y$ in the nonnegative orthant $\{v:v_i \ge 0\}$ that makes the largest angle with $x$. Intuitively, $y$ should be a standard basis vector (all zeros except one component). If this intuition holds, then $y$ should be the indicator vector for the smallest component of $x$. In terms of $p$ and $q$, this means $q$ should have all its mass on the least likely outcome under $p$, as you suspected.

---

Let us verify the "intuition" above by proving the minimization more explicitly.
The Lagrangian is
\begin{align}
\sum_i x_i y_i - \sum_i \lambda_i y_i + \mu\left(\sum_i y_i^2 - 1\right) .
\end{align}
The KKT conditions imply that for an optimal $y$ there exist $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda_i \ge 0$ such that the following hold.
\begin{align}
x_i-\lambda_i + 2 \mu y_i &=0,\\
\lambda_i y_i &= 0.
\end{align}
So, if $y_i \ne 0$, then $\lambda_i=0$ and thus $y_i = -\frac{x_i}{2\mu}$.

Also, $1 = \sum_i y_i^2 = \frac{1}{4\mu^2} \sum_{i : y_i \ne 0} x_i^2$ implies $\mu^2 = \frac{1}{4} \sum_{i:y_i \ne 0} x_i^2$

Finally, $0 \le y_i = - \frac{x_i}{2\mu}$ implies $\mu = -\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\sum_{i:y_i \ne 0} x_i^2}$.

Then, the quantity to minimize can be rewritten as
$$\sum_i x_i y_i = -\frac{1}{2\mu}\sum_{i : y_i \ne 0} x_i^2 = \sqrt{\sum_{i:y_i \ne 0} x_i^2}.$$
To make this right-hand side quantity as small as possible, we need many of the $y_i$ to equal zero. The best we can do is have all but one be zero (since we need $\sum_i y_i^2=1$) so that the sum $\sum_{i:y_i \ne 0} x_i^2$ consists of only one term, and in particular we should make this term be the smallest of the $x_i$.