# How can the maximal value of Hellinger Distance be reached? Consider 2 Gaussians

Tags: statistics, metric-spaces

Can we compute a closed-form for $\sigma_2$ and $\mu_2$ where the Hellinger Distance would be maximized?

We have the hellinger distance of 2 Gaussians.

$H^2(P,Q)=1-\sqrt{\frac{2\sigma_1\sigma_2}{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}}e^{-\frac{(\mu_1-\mu_2)^2}{4(\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)}}$

Actually, I have been following the optimization process in this link: [Finding the distribution with greatest Hellinger distance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2003106/finding-the-distribution-with-greatest-hellinger-distance). But haven't got any expected result...

I just forgot to add a condition here. $\sigma_2$ and $\mu_2$ are functions in terms of $x$. That is: $\sigma_2(x)$ and $\mu_2(x)$.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, if $\sigma_2$ and $\mu_2$ go infinite. The distance will reach the maximal. So, maybe there is no closed-form.